# metronic datatable 6*4 grid of user-images

Tags: laravel, datatable, metronic

I would like to know if it is possible to use datatables (Metronic Laravel Theme) to display a 6*4 grid of user-images instead of displaying the images row-by-row (the standard datatable behavior).  Anyone able to help?

ive just started on this so i don't want to waste a lot of time if it's not possible at all, this is what i have so far:

```
let members_datatable,
    members_element = $('...');




members_datatable = members_element.MyCustomDataTable({
    columns: [
            {
                field: 'id',
                title: members_element.data('column-id'),
                width: 50,
                template: function (row) {                    
                    return row.id;
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'first_name',
                title: members_element.data('column-name'),
                width: 150,
                template: function (row) {
                    let user_id = ...;
                    let user_company = ...;
                    let company_branche = ...;
                    return `<div class="mt-card-item">
                                <div class="mt-card-avatar mt-overlay-4">
                                    <img src="storage/public/userImages/${user_id}.jpg">
                                    <div class="mt-overlay">
                                        <h2>${user_company}</h2>
                                        <div class="mt-info font-white">
                                            <div class="mt-card-content">
                                                ${company_branche}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                }
            },
    ],
});
```

Comment: I don't know about Metronic laravel theme, but showing a table with images in it should be possible. What problems occur?

Comment: I can display images in a row but i would like to display the rows in a grid of 4 by 6 images instead of all rows below each other.

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14190/is-it-possible-to-visually-display-rows-horizontally-instead-of-vertically

Comment: Ok, so you want 'rows' within a row in a datatable? I think this is possible, but there are many ways of doing this. Could you post some code of what you have right now? Then I can customize an answer based on that.